# 3ware controller hotswap Linux

Tags: linux, 3ware

I have a server with a 3ware 9650SE controller running Debian.
The tw_cli utility shows this:

```
Ctl   Model        (V)Ports  Drives   Units   NotOpt  RRate   VRate  BBU
------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0    9650SE-8LPML 8         0        0       0       3       3      -        

Encls         Slots  Drives  Fans  TSUnits  PSUnits  
-----------------------------------------------------
e0            8      4       0     2        0
```

For E0 it shows:

```
Slot      Status          (V)Port       Identify
--------------------------------------------------
slot0     OK              -             Off           
slot1     OK              -             Off           
slot2     OK              -             Off           
slot3     OK              -             Off           
slot4     NO-DEVICE       -             Off           
slot5     NO-DEVICE       -             Off           
slot6     NO-DEVICE       -             Off           
slot7     NO-DEVICE       -             Off
```

The e0 should be the enclosure (SATA backplane). What I find interesting is that the utility shows C0 (the controller) has 0 drives connected to it. Someone who have experience with these type of cards could please explain it to me if this card does support hotswap for 100% and do I need to specify any additional command before replacing the drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should issue `/cx/py remove` command before removing specific drive from enclosure.
`/e0 show slots` should show you the ports associated with slots.
3ware 9650SE does support hot-swap for 100% ;)

Comment: Yes I could but what happens if I don't? The drives are in RAID1 mirror mode and my problem is that I don't exactly know which device is associated with which slot. In order logically it would be sdb->slot0,sdc->slot1,sdd->slot2 etc but isn't there a way to query this to be sure?

Comment: Play with the tw_cli : `/e0 show all`. In Linux you see units as devices, not drives themselves, so sdX will be a RAID1 unit not a phisical drive.